# Flutter: Passing multiple data between screens

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter. I'm trying to send multiple data to another screen:

```
// screen1.dart
..
Expanded(
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => new Screen2(name: thing.name, email: thing.email, address: thing.address, etc..),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
..


// screen2.dart

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget{
  Screen2({this.name}, {this.email}, {this.address}, etc..);
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String address;
  // etc
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() { return new Screen2State();}
}

class Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      ..
      child: Scaffold(
        ..
        new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(widget.name),
            new Text(widget.email),
            new Text(widget.address),
            etc..
          ],
        ),
      )
    )
}
```

But I get the error: `A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.`

The data is transferred from TextEditingControllers. It works when there is only 1 data transferred, but fails when there are 2 or more.

What's the correct way to send multiple data between screens?

Answer (score 3):

Everything looks fine but you need to change in the Screen 2 class constructor to this

```
Screen2({this.name, this.email, this.address, etc..});
```

Modified Code

```
// screen1.dart
..
Expanded(
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => new Screen2(name: thing.name, email: thing.email, address: thing.address, etc..),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
..


// screen2.dart

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget{
 Screen2({this.name, this.email, this.address, etc..});
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String address;
  // etc
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() { return new Screen2State();}
}

class Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      ..
      child: Scaffold(
        ..
        new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(widget.name),
            new Text(widget.email),
            new Text(widget.address),
            etc..
          ],
        ),
      )
    )
}
```

Note: Text Widget will not accept null values so please make sure you are passing all the values. Or you can initialize the variables with the default value to blank

```
final String name="";
final String email="";
final String address="";
```

Comment: I can't figure out your second approach, Please, Give some example...

Answer (score 2):

Consider passing the arguments through route arguments. Refer official doc here https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments